# Align Textviews in different rows using layout_weight parameter

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a list of flights on a listview. And I want to have them all of them align. I have used a LinearLayout, with gravity and padding. But I want to reduce the space for the 4th column, so then I can do bigger the size of the text. I have tried to set the layout_weight of this element to 0 and all of the rest to 1. But it doesnt work. So far I have this

[image: Table of flight boards]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you limited to ListView only? Because this here is a TableLayout thing..

Comment: I have no problem using anoother layout, but the TableLayout will give me the same result, wont it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `ListView` with a list of `LinearLayout` view's (I would go with a `TableRow` list put into a `TableLayout`), then I would suggest predefining the width of each column in percentage of the total space (i.e. how much of the screen would you allow the column to allocate). Something among the lines:

```
// basically you build your adapter here
LinearLayout.LayoutParams wrapWrapLinearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int[] columnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20};

ArrayList<LinearLayout> tableRows = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();//this is the adapter
LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
//add a header
row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapLinearLayoutParams);
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
row.setBackgroundColor(headerColor);
row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(headerForCol1, columnWidths[0]));
row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(headerForCol2, columnWidths[1]));
row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(headerForCol3, columnWidths[2]));
row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(headerForCol4, columnWidths[3]));
row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(headerForCol5, columnWidths[4]));
tableRows.add(row);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInTheFlightsTable; i++) {
    row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapLinearLayoutParams);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(col1Text, columnWidths[0]));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(col2Text, columnWidths[1]));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(col3Text, columnWidths[2]));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(col4Text, columnWidths[3]));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText(col5Text, columnWidths[4]));
    tableRows.add(row);
}

//util method
private TextView recyclableTextView;

public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth) {
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    recyclableTextView = new TextView(this);
    recyclableTextView.setText(text);
    recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
    recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
    return recyclableTextView;
}
```

I mean, the trick is that you predefine the percentage of screen allocated by each column.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

`LinearLayout` `LL1` containing the first 4 columns

`LinearLayout` `LL2` containing the last column

`RelativeLayout` `RL` contains `LL1` and `LL2`

You can now position `LL2` to the right of the container

**EDITED**

Comment: But then one row wont be align to the following one.